# Remove NA's in R data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I want to remove the NA's from this data.frame, so that I have two columns with 24 rows in each column.  Any ideas?  The data frame is named AtmWtAg.long.to.wide.  Not sure which command to use. !is.na   omit.na 

    `AtmWtAg.long.to.wide
             1           2
1  107.8681568          NA
2  107.8681465          NA
3  107.8681572          NA
4  107.8681785          NA
5  107.8681446          NA
6  107.8681903          NA
7  107.8681526          NA
8  107.8681494          NA
9  107.8681616          NA
10 107.8681587          NA
11 107.8681519          NA
12 107.8681486          NA
13 107.8681419          NA
14 107.8681569          NA
15 107.8681508          NA
16 107.8681672          NA
17 107.8681385          NA
18 107.8681518          NA
19 107.8681662          NA
20 107.8681424          NA
21 107.8681360          NA
22 107.8681333          NA
23 107.8681610          NA
24 107.8681477          NA
25          NA 107.8681079
26          NA 107.8681344
27          NA 107.8681513
28          NA 107.8681197
29          NA 107.8681604
30          NA 107.8681385
31          NA 107.8681642
32          NA 107.8681365
33          NA 107.8681151
34          NA 107.8681082
35          NA 107.8681517
36          NA 107.8681448
37          NA 107.8681198
38          NA 107.8681482
39          NA 107.8681334
40          NA 107.8681609
41          NA 107.8681101
42          NA 107.8681512
43          NA 107.8681469
44          NA 107.8681360
45          NA 107.8681254
46          NA 107.8681261
47          NA 107.8681450
48          NA 107.8681368`

Comment: [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) I reckon. I'm guessing you shouldn't have got this output in the first place. Show the code that made this "wide" dataset, and I reckon a simple change will fix it.

Comment: My question isn't a duplicate because I don't want to remove the rows with NA's in just the NA's.  I have to use the reshape command to go from long to wide.  In the wide format there should just be two columns with no NA's listed with length 24 rows as mentioned.

Comment: Probably not a duplicate, and `dat[] <- lapply(dat, na.omit)` may do what you want. My point however was that the dataset you show looks to have been reshaped incorrectly. If you go back one step to whatever created this dataset, you can probably solve your problem before it occurs. Is this the original data: http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/strd/anova/AtmWtAg.dat ?

Comment: For instance, using the `AtmWtAg` data from the link you could do `reshape(transform(AtmWtAg,id=ave(Instrument,Instrument,FUN=seq_along)), idvar="id", timevar="Instrument", direction="wide")` as a general solution or even just `unstack(AtmWtAg[2:1])` to reshape properly.

Comment: I have to use the reshape function, but here is what I  
have:      AtmWtAg.long.to.wide <- reshape(AtmWtAg.long1, v.names="AgWt", varying=list(names(AtmWtAg.wide)), idvar= "ID", ids=c("1", "2"), timevar="Instrument", direction="wide")                                                                 ID <- 1:nrow(AtmWtAg.long)
AtmWtAg.long1 <- cbind(AtmWtAg.long,ID)